# Класс с динамическим массивом

Tags: консоль, массивы, const, классы, c++

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблемка с классами!
В общем, мне нужно создать динамическую матрицу, а потом загнать ее числа в 1д массив!
Проблема в том, что просто в мейне все работает, а сделал прогу в виде класса - программа летит!
Нужна ваша помощь.))

```
#include "stdafx.h"  //here all librarys

class Array
{

    int size1;
    int size2;
    int **pA1;
    int * pA2;
    void init1()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < size1; i++)
            for (int j=0; j < size2; j++)
                pA1[i][j]=rand() % 20;
        cout << "init 1" <<endl;
    }

    void init2()
    {
        int index=0;
        for (int i=0; i < size1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < size2; j++)
            {
                pA2[index]=pA1[i][j];
                index++;
            }
        }
        cout << "init 2" <<endl;
    }
    void copy()
    {
        init2();
        int index=0;
        for (int i=0; i < size1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < size2; j++)
            {
                pA2[index]=pA1[i][j];
                index++;
            }
        }
        cout << "copy" <<endl;
    }
public:

    Array(int SIZE1,int SIZE2)
    {
        size1=SIZE1;
        size2=SIZE2;
        int **pA1=new int *[size1];
        for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
           pA1[i]=new int[size2];
        int * pA2 =new int [size2*size1];
        cout << "const" <<endl;
    }

    void show1()
    {
        copy();
        cout << "Your 2D array: " <<endl;
        for (int i=0; i < size1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < size2; j++)
            {
                cout <<setw(3)<<pA1[i][j] <<' ';
            }
            cout <<endl;
        }
        cout << "show 1" <<endl;
    }

    void show2()
    {
        init2();
        cout  <<endl<<endl<< "Your combined 1D array:" <<endl; 
        for(int i=0; i<size2*size1; i++)
            cout << pA2[i] <<' ';
        cout <<endl;
        cout << "show 2" <<endl;
    }

    void delet()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
            delete []pA1[i];
        delete []pA2;
        cout << "delete" <<endl;
    }
};

int _tmain()
{

        int size1=0,size2=0;
    cout << "How many columns you want: ";
    cin >>size2;
        cout << "How many rows you want: "; 
    cin >>size1;
    Array ar1(size1,size2);
    ar1.show1();
    ar1.show2();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявили в классе 2d массив pA1 и 1d массив pA2. Затем в конструкторе заново объявляете и  инициализируете их.
Нужно убрать объявление из конструктора:

```
Array(int SIZE1,int SIZE2)
    {
        size1=SIZE1;
        size2=SIZE2;
        pA1=new int *[size1];
        for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
           pA1[i]=new int[size2];
        pA2 =new int [size2*size1];
        cout << "const" <<endl;
    }
```

P.S. Копировать массивы проще при помощи memcpy, так как 2d и 1d массивы - это просто область памяти: `memcpy(pA2,pA1,size1*size2*sizeof(int));`.

Comment: Тупая ошибка. ) Спасибо большое! И отдельное за копирование. ))